# What is Hubbles WFC3 "UVIS 47 G200" filter? What is it used for? How to find an example?

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, hubble-telescope, instruments

Extensive reading for [Are the dispersion directions of the prism and the grating in Hubble WFC3 UVIS G280 perpendicular? Can we call this a "grism"? With cross-disparsion?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47075/7982) led me to [Instrument Science Report WFC3 2003-02; WFC3 UVIS Filters: Measured Throughput and Comparison to Specifications](https://www.stsci.edu/files/live/sites/www/files/home/hst/instrumentation/wfc3/documentation/instrument-science-reports-isrs/_documents/2003/WFC3-2003-02.pdf).

Table 1: "UVIS Filter Performance Specifications from Version D JPL Spec or CEI" lists near the bottom

```
Fnumber  Fname   Lam0   FWHM  lam -50 ... lam +50 ... Description
-------  -----  ------  ----  -------     -------     -----------
UVIS 47  G200   2775.0  1850    1800  ...   3650  ...   UV prism
```

**Question:** What is Hubbles WFC3 "UVIS 47 G200" filter? Is it just a prism or is it a combination of a prism and a filter?

What is it used for?

How can I find an example of how it has been used in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is a typo. In Tables 4 and 5 of the same document, "UVIS 47" is listed as "g280", which is the grism you are curious about.

A perusal of several other *HST* documents (e.g., various *Wide Field Camera 3 Instrument Handbooks*) turns up no mention of a "G200" element, and searches of the [HST archive](https://mast.stsci.edu/search/hst/ui/#/) turn up nothing if "G200" is entered in the "Filter/Grating" field. (Entering "G280" turns up observations with that grism.)

Comment: nice detective work, thanks!